# Parallelogram with an angle and the midpoint of a side

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$M$ is the midpoint of the side $AB$ of a parallelogram $ABCD$. Find the perimeter of the parallelogram if $MD=4,MC=6$ and $\measuredangle BAD=60^\circ$.

[image]

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB\Rightarrow AM=BM=x$ and $AD=BC=y$. We are supposed to find $P_{ABCD}=2(AB+AD)=2(2x+y)=4x+2y$. Two cosine rules for $\triangle AMD$ and $\triangle MBC$ give $$DM^2=AM^2+AD^2-2AM.AD\cos60^\circ\\x^2+y^2-xy=16\\MC^2=MB^2+BC^2-2MB.BC\cos120^\circ\\x^2+y^2+xy=36$$ This seems useless for the perimeter (we can find the area, though).

Comment: Subtracting the first equation from the second one results in  $xy=10$. But then $ y=10/x$ and $x^2+\frac{100}{x^2}-10=16$ which can be solved for $ x^2$.

Comment: Also, if $xy=10$ then $(x+y)^2-10=36 \implies x+y=\sqrt 46$

Comment: An easier method for finding $2(x+y)$ directly is to use  $xy=10$ to get $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+xy+xy=36+10=46$, i.e. , $2(x+y)=2\sqrt{46}$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger, thank you for the response. But why do we need $2(x+y)$?

Comment: I mixed up the meaning of $x$ and $y$ and assumed the perimeter to be $2(x+y)$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible values of perimeter.

$x^2+y^2-xy=16$, $x^2+y^2+xy=36$ $\Rightarrow x^2+y^2=26$, $xy=10$ $\Rightarrow (x+y)^2=46$, $(x-y)^2=6$ $\Rightarrow$
$x+y=\sqrt{46}$, $x-y=\pm\sqrt{6}$ $\Rightarrow 4x+2y=3(x+y)+(x-y)=3\sqrt{46}\pm\sqrt{6}$.